# Ошибка в Android Studio | AppTheme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Как исправит ошибку?

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.(ActionBarContainer.java:64)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:59)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:241)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:153)
>   [image: Ошибка в AppCompat ActionBar]

Answer (score 0):

нужно просто сменить стили в файле "res/values/styles.xml". Если это не помогло, то вот есть список действий, который скорее всего поможет решить вам данную проблему. [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too)